# How can I reduce the file size of a photographic background image without losing quality?

Tags: image, background, photoshop

I have a very large background image ~400k.  If I reduce the quality in Photoshop to say (4) it will shrink it down to ~180k - still big but much more manageable.  Are there any other good methods at reducing file size without losing a ton of quality?  My PSD for my background image is basically a giant collage - some of the pics have color and the rest are desaturated.  I'd love to save as black and white but need some of those color images.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: A background image for what? How is the image being used?

Comment: This does not seem to be directly related to programming.  Nevertheless, why don't you post a sample of the image you are trying to compress.  Also, will you accept any format besides .jpg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

have you tried to save the image in Photoshop by "Save for web and devices"?